# what will be the PDF of the magnitude of this random variable x+j y?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, complex-numbers, random-variables

if we have  a complex random variable [x+j*y] where (j :sqrt(-1)) and x,y both have Gaussian distribution and statistically **dependent** , so what will be the distribution (PDF) of the magnitude of this random variable also the PDF of the phase in this case ?

Comment: Did you eventually find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, the magnitude will be a Rice distribution.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution  If it is zero mean for x and y, then the phase will be uniform.

Comment: but for rice distribution x,y should be statistically independent but in my case they are dependent